# Issue with getting element using ElementId

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript

I am trying to get the apex input element value using document.getElementById() method but facing some issues with that. I got the element id by inspecting that element in chrome. The id which I got is "j_id0:j_id11:j_id40:j_id44:ListingName". When I am trying to use below method , I am getting null result :

```
document.getElementById("j_id0:j_id11:j_id40:j_id44:ListingName")
```

[image]

I have tried this also with a simple code as below but still it is showing "null" in alert message :

```
<apex:page standardController="Account">
  <apex:form >
      <apex:inputField value="{!Account.name}" id="accName"/>
      <apex:commandButton value="Test" onclick="testFunction(); return false;"/>
  </apex:form>
  <script>
  function testFunction(){
      alert(document.getElementById('{!$Component.accName}'));
  }
  </script>
</apex:page>
```

Can anyone suggest what I am missing or doing wrong ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should work perfectly fine. Please check back your "html id" twice. If it helps, I have given here what I tried.

Here is what I tried.

```
<apex:commandButton action="{!edit}" id="edit" value="Edit" onmouseover="myalert();"/>

function myalert(){
       alert(document.getElementById("j_id0:j_id1:j_id8:j_id9:0:accountName"));
}
```

[image]

**Update:**

Try your code with ids assigned to all the levels to have proper control.

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" id="accPage">
  <apex:form id="accform" >
      <apex:inputField value="{!Account.name}" id="accName"/>
      <apex:commandButton value="Test" onclick="testFunction(); return false;"/>
  </apex:form>
  <script>
  function testFunction(){
      alert(document.getElementById('{!$Component.accPage.accform.accName}'));
  }
  </script>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: I have tried below code , but still the alert is showing null :

<apex:page standardController="Account">
  <apex:form >
      <apex:inputField value="{!Account.name}" id="accName"/>
      <apex:commandButton value="Test" onclick="testFunction(); return false;"/>
  </apex:form>
  <script>
  function testFunction(){
      alert(document.getElementById('{!$Component.accName}'));
  }
  </script>
</apex:page>

Comment: See my updated answer.

Comment: This isn't an ideal solution.  That path is subject to change based on the visualforce rendering engine.  See supporting best practice document here:  http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_best_practices_accessing_id.htm

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the VisualForce $Component function to grab the proper name.  Try this

`document.getElementById('{!$Component.ListingName}')`

You can also chain the $Component string if you have other named elements in the DOM.

Here is the documentation on $Component:  http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_variables_global_component.htm

Comment: The `{!$Component.ListingName}` markup won't work directly in the browser console as the initial question's image describes is being done. That said, this is the appropriate mechanism to get a dynamically generated element's ID within a VF page itself.

Comment: @MarkPond Excellent point, this won't work for debugging in the chrome console, as it happens when the VF is rendered.  In the console you can find elements with the built in $$ function and the ends with selector.

$$('[id$="ListingName"]')

Comment: Thanks for teaching me something new! I was unaware that in most modern browser consoles `$$` is a shortcut to `document.querySelectorAll()`. Very cool, I love this community. http://stackoverflow.com/a/10308917/1947121

Comment: Laziness for the win!  Shortcuts are great.

Comment: @Mark Pond Can you please provide solution to my problem ?

Comment: @S.Sharma - I don't recommend using the method you're using currently.  The closest I recommend to this approach is using a selector like $= (ends with).  The reason is the first part of that Id is dynamic.  It is built by the VF rendering engine based on the markup on the page.  If you make any changes to the DOM, you'll have to re-do your Id each time.  Sometimes certain elements that are nested require you to use the parent Ids.

Here is the documentation:  http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_variables_global_component.htm